# Developing an Online Webcam Video Surveillance System in .NET (Real Time Video Streaming Issues)

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, sockets, video-streaming

I'm working on an application that is joining two projects in two different courses in my Software Engineering degree:

SWE 490: Component Based Software Engineering
SWE 344: IP and Client Server programing

Here's what's my application about :

**Client Side (Desktop Based)**: Main function is to capture the webcam video and stream it to the server.
**Server Side (Web Based)**: Main function is to receive the streamed video from the client and display it on the website in real time.

**Brief Description of the application :**
The users will be able to monitor their Webcams remotely by streaming their webcams output to a remote server that is accessible via the web. The system will also serve as a motion detection system (if activated by the user) to notify the users via email if any motion has been detected on their webcams. In addition the system also allows users to schedule recordings and watch them online through live streaming.

---

I'm preparing a proposal for the project and I've made some initial plans for the system structure that is represented below :

**Client Side Components (Desktop) :**

[image: Client Side Components]

**Server Side Components (Web Server) :**

[image]

**My Question :**

My main issues are with the real time video streaming (sending and receiving components) as this is a new topic for me.

I know I can program a socket and send the captured videos as a stream of bytes to the main server, but **what I'm concerned about is how am i going to display the received stream on the web browser at the server side**.

My situation is similar to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359789/video-capturing-uploading-processing-streaming-back-net-c) except that it's for video streaming and not image streaming.

**I've been reading some articles and it seems like it can be done using Silverlight and I'm hoping someone can point me to the right direction.**

**Your opinions on the project in general are more than welcomed.**

Comment: Hi @Manaf Abu.Rous, I am in a similar situation. If you have managed to solve the problem can you please let me know how you could do that?

Answer (score -1):

I agree that Silverlight should probably be your first stop.

You can start here:
http://www.silverlight.net/community/samples/silverlight-samples/video-chat-35809/

[EDIT: 28/02/2014]
Okay so this is obviously no longer valid, you can stop down voting it already ...

Comment: Thanks for the link, Examples are great tool to learn only if you do understand the idea which is what I'm lacking right now. Plus the question is tagged with C# ,,, and the example above is in VB :\